# How to pull first timestamp from each "group" of events that happen every twelve hours

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark

Let's say we have a table with two columns: station_id and timestamp. I implemented two stations and they are set to stream weather changes approximately every 12 hours. Those streams stream for a couple of minutes.

Let's take this table as a sample:

```
station_id          timestamp
----------------------------------
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:10
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:13
station_1      2019-06-02 21:05:10
station_1      2019-06-02 21:08:15
station_2      2019-06-02 09:30:10
station_2      2019-06-02 09:31:10
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:11
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:12
```

My goal is to analyze streamed data and check if both of my streamers streamed regularly as they should. By regularly I mean every 12 hours.

The output should look something like this

```
station_id          timestamp
----------------------------------
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:10
station_1      2019-06-02 21:05:10
station_2      2019-06-02 09:30:10
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:11
```

I took into account only one day but it should be able to handle a few days of data.

I guess I need to group by station_id and an interval somehow and show only the interval start timestamp

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what it is you're trying to return.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My goal was to take every few minutes streamers interval(which happens every 12 hours) extract first streaming data row from that interval and show that in tableau. If I see value on the graph for a certain station in certain time it means station did it's job as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by station order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where prev_timestamp is null or
      prev_timestamp < timestamp - interval 11 hour;
```

This uses 11 hours rather than 12 hours just to provide some leeway for the repeated measurements.

Note that date/time functions vary depending on the database.  The above works in MySQL.  It might be slightly different in another database.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, I am not as proficient as I should be in SQL. I still haven't used the lag function as a student. I will give it a look asap. I decided randomly whom to give "answered" tag. I l investigate your solution more deeply.

Comment: @stevo92 . . . There is no comparison.  `lag()` is the right way to approach this, not a self-join.